# RSS feed for specific tags on medium.com?

Tags: rss, medium

I just want to know how to create RSS feed for specific tags on Medium.com, like I'm interested in 'technology' posts on medium.com and I want to follow them via Feedly or Inoreader. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the RSS feed for any tag by any author using the URL in this format:

```
https://medium.com/feed/tag/technology
```

However, there's no mention of this at [Medium Support](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/214874118-Where-are-RSS-feeds-). There they only mention feeds for @usernames and publications.

Medium feeds also appear to be just excerpts, not full feeds.